# Symfony2 getters, setters, add and remove

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, relationships

I'm getting really confused by entity properties and what they mean. I understand that get and set allow the application to interact with protected and private properties, but what about add and remove?

When running the command

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities bundle:entity
```

Sometimes it will generate getters and setters and other times it will generate add and remove properties (and usually a get method as well). I've noticed that it also sometimes depends on the relationship with other entities (i.e. OnetoMany), but not always :-S

Nowhere in the Symfony documentation that I can find is this addressed, and it's causing me to see the message "Neither the property "x" nor one of the methods exist and have public access" way too often. Can anybody provide a succinct explanation of this?

Comment: `addX()` and `removeX()` methods are generated when the property is a collection of objects (`OneToMany`, `ManyToMany`) since you usually want to add or remove only one object at a time in the relation, rather than setting (or unsetting) a whole set of object at one time. The `getX()` method should always be there since you usually want to avoid having public properties when programming in OOP.

Comment: Thanks, I also could do with clarification on when to use ManyToOne and OneToMany. I.e. if a user has many songs, and you add a user to the database along with their songs, is it right to include a ManyToOne property for songs on the user entity? Or is is OneToMany because it's inside the the User entity?

Comment: In this particular case, you would at least need a `ManyToOne` property in the song entity, since it's the owning side of the relation, which means the song table will contain the user's id to whom the song is attached to. You could also inverse the relation by adding a `OneToMany` relation in the user entity. Take a look at this doc page to learn more about owning and inverse sides in a relation : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

Answer (score 1):

`add` and `remove` are used to deal with collections. If for example your Entity (Let's say `A`) contains a collection of `B` elements, then the command will provide an `addB()` and a `removeB()` public methods to help you add and remove elements from your collection. It'll also provide a getter which returns the whole collection.

The command generates methods based on the `type` of attributes you're working with (ArrayCollection, string, ...)

Answer (score 1):

For xxxToMany associations, Doctrine will generate a "adder" and a "remover" instead of a plain setter. The idea is to easily add and/or remove a single object from the collection without needing to pass around the entire collection everytime to the setter.

Note though that these generated methods are an implementation detail you are free to revise. If you prefer a single setter method for example, feel free to implement that one yourself.

I personally don't rely on the accessor generation of Doctrine anymore. Doing it manually allows greater control of your entity's API, and is also quite easy in an IDE like Netbeans or PHPStorm.

Comment: So what I'm finding strange is my XToMany relationships don't generate setters - why is this? It screws things up when I'm needing to set things through a form.